# How to link the dialog button to main window function and also make close event separate from the function

Tags: python, qdialog, pyside2

What I am trying to do, is to open a dialog from the mainwindow menu, and in the dialog, there are some inputs, either linetextedit or spinbox, or comboboxes... And there is one button to close the dialog and pass the data to mainwindow. In the mainwindow, some operations are made. In the example I made, the operations are adding the two numbers from the dialog together show in the mainwindow, write a txt file to local disk and open the file using QDesktopServices.

Even not elegant, I made this works but I found that **in the dialog, the adding and display and the open external file are still executed even if I close the dialog using the 'x' on the upperright corner**. I only want to link the function to the button but not the close event.

Here I paste the converted py files from ui and also the main file.

mainwindowui.py

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(486, 497)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 486, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionOpenLocal = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpenLocal.setObjectName("actionOpenLocal")
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionOpenLocal)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, -1))
        self.label.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Summation", None, -1))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "File", None, -1))
        self.actionOpenLocal.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "OpenLocal", None, -1))
```

dialogui.py

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(320, 237)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Dialog)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.labelA = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.labelA.setObjectName("labelA")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.labelA, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.alineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.alineEdit.setObjectName("alineEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.alineEdit, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.labelB = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.labelB.setObjectName("labelB")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.labelB, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.blineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.blineEdit.setObjectName("blineEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.blineEdit, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 2, 0, 1, 2)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None, -1))
        self.labelA.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "inputA", None, -1))
        self.labelB.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "inputB", None, -1))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Dialog", "OpenPdf", None, -1))
```

and the main.py

```
import sys
import os

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from mainwindowui import Ui_MainWindow
from dialogui import Ui_Dialog


class fileDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog,Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Open File")
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.close)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.actionOpenLocal.triggered.connect(self.startDialog)
        self.show()

    def startDialog(self):
        dlg = fileDialog(self)
        dlg.exec_()
        dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.getDialogInfo(dlg))


    def getDialogInfo(self,dialogue):
        self.avalue = float(dialogue.alineEdit.text())
        self.bvalue = float(dialogue.blineEdit.text())
        sum = str(self.avalue+self.bvalue)
        self.lineEdit.setText(sum)
        file = open("result.txt","w")
        file.write(sum)
        file.close()

        QtGui.QDesktopServices.openUrl(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(currentdir +"/result.txt"))


if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    currentdir = os.getcwd()
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    ret = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(ret)
```

And also if someone can correct the parts which seems not not so standard, I am also very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has several errors:

- The line `dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.getDialogInfo(dlg))` does not make sense, let's analyze a bit, what result has `self.getDialogInfo(dlg)`, the function `getDialogInfo` performs a task but does not return anything that equals return a `None` so the initial code equals `dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(None)`, it does the task you want but the connection is unnecessary.
- The dialog returns a code when you call `exec_()` and it is used to discriminate if the task is accepted or not since that is the task of a dialog box. That code is returned only when you call the `accept()` or `reject()` method that closes the window, so instead of the button calling `close()` you must call `accept()`, so when you close the window using the X button it will internally call `reject()`, so you can discriminate between each button.
- Do not use sum since it is the name of a function and it is considered a reserved word, doing so could cause problems in the future.
- Use with to open a file as it automatically closes the file when it is exited.
- Do not concatenate path manually because the concatenation is dependent on the platform, you better use the functions provided by the library `os`.
- Use the new connection syntax, it's more readable

Considering the above, the following solution is obtained:

```
import os
import sys

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from mainwindowui import Ui_MainWindow
from dialogui import Ui_Dialog


class fileDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Open File")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.accept)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.actionOpenLocal.triggered.connect(self.startDialog)
        self.show()

    def startDialog(self):
        dlg = fileDialog(self)
        if dlg.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
            self.getDialogInfo(dlg)

    def getDialogInfo(self, dialogue):
        self.avalue = float(dialogue.alineEdit.text())
        self.bvalue = float(dialogue.blineEdit.text())
        res = str(self.avalue+self.bvalue)
        self.lineEdit.setText(res)
        with open("result.txt","w") as file:
            file.write(res)
        QtGui.QDesktopServices.openUrl(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.path.join(currentdir,"result.txt")))


if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    currentdir = os.getcwd()
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    ret = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(ret)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use signals and slots.

```
import sys
import os

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from mainwindowui import Ui_MainWindow
from dialogui import Ui_Dialog


class fileDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog,Ui_Dialog):
    sig_complete = QtCore.Signal(dict)
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Open File")
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.slt_save)

    def slt_save(self):
        self.sig_complete.emit({"aline": self.alineEdit.text(), "bline": self.blineEdit.text()})
        self.close()

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.actionOpenLocal.triggered.connect(self.startDialog)
        self.show()

    def startDialog(self):
        dlg = fileDialog(self)
        dlg.sig_complete.connect(self.getDialogInfo)
        dlg.exec_()

    def getDialogInfo(self,data_dict):
        self.avalue = float(data_dict["aline"])
        self.bvalue = float(data_dict["bline"])
        sum = str(self.avalue+self.bvalue)
        self.lineEdit.setText(sum)
        file = open("result.txt","w")
        file.write(sum)
        file.close()
        QtGui.QDesktopServices.openUrl(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(currentdir +"/result.txt"))


if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    currentdir = os.getcwd()
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    ret = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(ret)
```

Comment: The reply works like a charm and I think using a custom signal in this reply is powerful and more customizable.  I accept the answer by @eyllanesc is because he did a thorough analysis and the solution also works well.